# Implementing Glicko Rating in Python

Tags: algorithms, python

Recently, I've been trying to implement some working version of the [Glicko Rating System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glicko_rating_system) for fun.

However, I fail to understand how to programmatically isolate `R` in Step 2. As you can see `R` appears on both sides of the equation and for a variable number of instances. How would I programatically solve for `R` using python?

Thanks for any help :)

EDIT: Actually shouldn't the `R` in step 2 be `R_0` on the right hand side of the equation? Is this a typo? Note in ["The Glicko system" by Professor Mark E. Glickman](http://www.glicko.net/glicko/glicko.pdf), the equations are identical except for all `R`s being on one side and `R'` being on the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/sublee/glicko it's a python implention of both the glicko and the glicko-2 rating system

Comment: A better alternative to glicko could be trueskill.it was made by microsoft and is used by xbox live. Have a look at: [link](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/trueskill/) there is a python module for it: [link](http://pythonhosted.org/trueskill/)

Comment: "TrueSkill is patented, and the name is trademarked, so therefore it is limited to Microsoft projects and commercial projects that obtain a license to use the algorithm."